# In new logcat of Android Studio, how can I increase tab column width more than 35?

Tags: android-studio

From Android Studio Dolphin,
New logcat is introduced and it has cool view.

But, it is hard to see tag in log because it limits tag column width.

It is not possible to increate tag column width in settings, so I cannot set the value more than 35.

[image: android studio logcat settings]

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to increase it forcefully.

**1. Find Android Studio logcat settings file**

(ex. Windows, Android Studio Hedgehog)

`C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2023.1\options\androidLogcatFormattingOptions.xml)`

refer to Android Developer to find settings file location for your os
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

**2. Find tab width value**

`...,'tagFormat':{'maxLength':35,...`

**3. Change it and save the file**

`...,'tagFormat':{'maxLength':70,...`

**4. Restart Android Studio**

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find that file on Mac (have checked the location suggested in the link)

Comment: @aaronmarino For mac the file is in:

/Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudioPreview2023.2/options/androidLogcatFormattingOptions.xml